# Spring JPA native query to call store procedrure gives “No converter found capable of converting from type”

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA and I need to have a native query to call stored procedure. From the result, I need to get only two fields i.e. code and msg. I made a class which contain two field code and msg. It isn't working, this is the error I'm getting:

> Failed to complete request:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
>   to type [com.evampsaanga.sez.model.dto.NtnVerification]

So, here's my code:

```
public interface CacheOtpRepository extends JpaRepository<CacheOtp, Long> {

    @Query(value = "{call verify_ntn_opt_prc(:ntnNumber, :otpCode)}", nativeQuery = true)
        NtnVerification verifyNtnByOtpStoredProcedure(@Param("ntnNumber") String ntnNumber, @Param("otpCode") String otpCode);
    }

}
```

Here is my dto class

```
public class NtnVerification {

    private int code;
    private String msg;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

Here is the result when i call stored procedure using mysql workbench

[image: Here is the result when i call stored procedure using mysql workbench]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using spring data JPA interface projection

```
public interface NtnVerification {
  public int getCode;();
  public String getMsg();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `NtnVerification` from a JpaRepository that takes care of the persistance of `CacheOtp`. You can either use Projections as mentioned by *@ashish* or call the procedure the Spring data jpa way.

The **Spring data jpa**  way to call a Stored Procudure is to use `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` on your entity class and then use `@Procedure` in your JPA repositories.

**Your Entity**

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME",
    procedureName = "PROCEDURE_NAME_IN_THE_DATABASE",
    parameters = {
          ...
          ...
    }
)})    
@Entity
public class NtnVerification {
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Your Repository**

```
@Transactional
public interface NtnVerificationRepository extends CrudRepository<NtnVerification , Long> {

    ...    

    @Procedure(name = YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME)
    List<NtnVerification> getNtnVerifications();

}
```

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/stored-procedure-ref-cursor.html) for a more detailed explanation.