# JPA Native Query ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to join some tables and return results from it.
The query is in JpaRepository

```
   @Query(value = " select mt.* from user_data d \n" +
        "  join user_data_marks dm on dm.user_data_marks_id=d.id\n" +
        "  join point mt on mt.point_id= dm.user_data_point_id" +
        "  where mt.point_time = :pointTime ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Point> findAllByPointTime(@Param("pointTime") LocalDate today);
```

But when the query is executed in a test I get:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.project.application.model.user.Point] for value '{1, 2019-12-26, ADVANCED}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [com.project.application.model.user.Point].
```

I guess the problem is in the query itself, but can't figure out why it doesn't want to return an object of type Point?

UPDATED: Point entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "point")
public class Point{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "point_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "point_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PointType pointType;

@Column(name = "point_time")
private LocalDate pointTime;
```

Comment: specify your column names in your select statement, then  add `@AllArgumentConstrucotor` and `@NoArgumentConstructor`.

Comment: Did you try your query on your database before?

Comment: You might be facing same issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477716/spring-jpa-native-query-to-call-store-procedrure-gives-no-converter-found-capab/59477901?noredirect=1#comment105135384_59477901

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [`@SqlResultSetMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html). Example of usage is in the provided JavaDoc.

Apart ot that the Query seems so simple that you could rewrite it to a JPQL Query which would give you benefits like platform independency, speed because it would be it would use a prepared statement and error checking because Spring Data JPA validates by default every JPQL Query at bootstrap time.

Answer (score -1):

`select mt.* from user_data d`

Why not:

`select p from Point p`

?